What problem in the C++ code for function template code?
In Chapter 2 Function Template of the book C++ templates, 1st Edition, there is a code example which the book say it has problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

// maximum of two values of any type (call-by-reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    printf("call 1 \n");
    return  a < b  ?  b : a;
}

// maximum of two C-strings (call-by-value)
inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
{ 
    printf("call 2 %s %s\n", a, b);
    return  std::strcmp(a,b) < 0  ?  b : a;
}

// maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference)
template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max (max(a,b), c);  // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
}

int main ()
{
    //::max(7, 42, 68);     // OK

    const char* s1 = "frederic";
    const char* s2 = "anica";
    const char* s3 = "lucas";
    ::max(s1, s2, s3);    // ERROR
    printf("finish");

}

I try it on compiler explorer, it can work, although there is compiler warning:
<source>:24:16: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   24 |     return max (max(a,b), c);  // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
      |            ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~

I can't understand what it means for "returning reference to temporary". Does it mean max(a,b) return reference to temporary? For this example,  as the passed char* pointer is always valid, any potential problem here?
Thanks

Does this answer your question? Returning const reference

Doesn't the box explain the problem? max (max(a,b), c) in this case returns const char* by value, which a temporary. You then return a reference to it, and the temporary dies right after returning from the function.

By the way, it would be fine if you didn't have a special case for const char*. That special case is arguably pointless; there's std::string and std::string_view which have < operators.
